# Remove indent for headed section, subsection and body text

Tags: indentation

Code sample:

```
\usepackage{resume}
\begin{document}  % begin the content of the document


\roottitle{RootTitle}

\headedsection  % sets the header for the section and includes any subsections
  {HeadedSection}
  {%
  \headedsubsection
    {HeadedSubSection}
   
    {\bodytext{
    BodyText
    }}
}

\end{document}
```

How it looks:

[image]

I want to remove the indent for each: headed section, subsection and body text

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. My suggestion it is to put a complete code: what is `\roottitle`?

Comment: none of the commands you show are standard commands and you give no indication of their definition so it is impossible to suggest how to change unseen code. The standard classes do not indent sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the package `titlesec`. It provides the function `\titleformat{...}`, which allows you to format the different tittles defined by default. I'm providing you with a basic template that you can modify, I think that the comments that I have included will provide enough information for you to edit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}           % Change title format

\titleformat{\section}
{\bfseries} % format
{}          % label
{0.0cm}     % separation between label and body
{}          % code preceding title body
[]          % code following title body

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\bfseries} % format
{}          % label
{0.0cm}     % separation between label and body
{}          % code preceding title body
[]          % code following title body

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\bfseries} % format
{}          % label
{0.0cm}     % separation between label and body
{}          % code preceding title body
[]          % code following title body

\begin{document}  % begin the content of the document


\section{RootTitle}
\subsection{HeadedSection}
\subsubsection{HeadedSubSection}
body text

\end{document}
```

The final result looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwomY.png]